# using iframe googledocviewer - index google this?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I used the `googledocviewer` to view some word an excel sheets on my site:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://domain.de/media/dokumente/worddocument.doc&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The documents are on MY server.
It works fine, but now my question:

Generally, on the live site, all IP´s are on my server blacklisted, because only 5 specially IP´s have access to the site.

So, the iframe try to load the googledocviewer, but google is blacklistet (on my server, because it´s not an ip from the 5)

So, the screen shows:
no document available.

If I set the `googledocviewer` IP to my whitelist - indexing Google all my documents and save they at any google-server?

The documents are private !!! No other IP´s and users is allowed, to see this docs.

My suspicion:

Because I use the `googledocs` viewer and set the `googledocsviewer` IP to a whitelist, other users can now access to these private documents....

Sorry for my bad english...I'll work on it.

Best regards,
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Whitelist domains for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020), you can still set which files can be shared and you also can choose more permissive settings to be sure that you don't share confidential files.

> You can allow file sharing in Google Drive for organizations that you trust by whitelisting their domain. After you whitelist a domain, you then grant Drive access so that users in your organization can share files and folders with users in the trusted domain.

Furthermore, it was also mentioned in grant sharing access for whitelisted domains

> For **Google Apps Unlimited**, **Google Apps for Education**, and **Google Apps for Nonprofits**, you grant file sharing access by changing Drive sharing settings. For details, see [Set file sharing permissions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781#whitelisted).
>
> For **Google Apps for Education**, you grant access to classes by changing Classroom settings. For details, see [Whitelist domains for Classroom](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6173514).